# /beans of spring boot actuator not accessible

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Tried with a simple spring boot application with actuator dependency, but not able to access http://localhost:8080/actuator/beans

I am able to access http://localhost:8080/actuator with the following output :

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator","templated":false},"health-component-instance":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/{component}/{instance}","templated":true},"health-component":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/{component}","templated":true},"health":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health","templated":false},"info":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/info","templated":false}}}
```

ALso majorly the following url's are not accessible listed from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators)

```
/auditevents – lists security audit-related events such as user login/logout. Also, we can filter by principal or type among others fields
/beans – returns all available beans in our BeanFactory. Unlike 
/auditevents, it doesn’t support filtering
/conditions – formerly known as /autoconfig, builds a report of conditions around auto-configuration
/configprops – allows us to fetch all @ConfigurationProperties beans
/env – returns the current environment properties. Additionally, we can retrieve single properties
/flyway – provides details about our Flyway database migrations
/health – summarises the health status of our application
/heapdump – builds and returns a heap dump from the JVM used by our application
/info – returns general information. It might be custom data, build information or details about the latest commit
/liquibase – behaves like /flyway but for Liquibase
/logfile – returns ordinary application logs
/loggers – enables us to query and modify the logging level of our application
/metrics – details metrics of our application. This might include generic metrics as well as custom ones
 /prometheus – returns metrics like the previous one, but formatted to work with a Prometheus server
/scheduledtasks – provides details about every scheduled task within our application
/sessions – lists HTTP sessions given we are using Spring Session
/shutdown – performs a graceful shutdown of the application
/threaddump – dumps the thread information of the underlying JVM
```

Answer (score 8):

`Default  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include, info, health`
As `actuator/health` and `actuator/info` are provided by default . so that you will get the information

> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = *  //will allow all endpoints
>   to be exposed

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info # Endpoint IDs that should be included or '*' for all.
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude= # Endpoint IDs that should be excluded or '*' for all.
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator # Base path for Web endpoints. Relative to server.servlet.context-path or management.server.servlet.context-path if management.server.port is configured.
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping= # Mapping between endpoint IDs and the path that should expose them.
```

**Securing Endpoint**

```
management.endpoint.health.roles= # Roles used to determine whether or not a user is authorized to be shown details. When empty, all authenticated users are authorized. //for health

management.endpoint.health.show-details=always,never # When to show full health details.
```

**Enable/Disable endpoints**

```
management.endpoint.(endpointName).enabled=true # Whether to enable the health endpoint.
e.g. management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
```

Refer [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for Manual Configurations

Refer [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-features.html) for More Details